# Rename a taxonomy vocabulary during migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm working on a custom migration for taxonomy vocabulary and I was wondering if there is a way to rename a vocabulary during migration?
my d7 vocabulary name is `staff` and I wanted to be migrated to d8 as `departments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved by using [static_map](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21StaticMap.php/class/StaticMap) plugin:

```
plugin: static_map
  bypass: true
  map:
    staff: departments
```